# Relations and functions

Tags: relations

$$
g(x) = e^x-1, x\in\mathbb R\\
h(x) = \ln(\ln x),x>1\\
$$
By restricting the domain of $g$ to $(\alpha, \infty)$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, find the smallest value of $\alpha$ in exact form such that the composite function $h\circ g$ exists. Define $h \circ g$.

My question: I don't understand why the restricted range of the g(x) is (1,∞)

Comment: What do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h\circ g(x)=h(g(x))=\ln(\ln(e^x-1))$ will be well defined if $\ln(e^x-1)$ is well defined and positive.

For this we need $e^x-1>1$ or equivalently $x>\ln2$.

Comment: Where do you get ln2 from? Is it from 1=e^a -1 -> e^a =2 ?

Comment: $e^x-1>1\iff e^x>2\iff x>\ln2$